# To generate 10 random numbers between -1.5 and 1.5 and write them in a ran.dat file

Tags: c

**I have tried this**

*Fix the range and also compute average and number of data greater than average*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    float num;
    srand(time(NULL));

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("ran.dat", "w");

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        num = rand() % (-1.5,1.5);
        fprintf(fp, "%f\n", num);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (5,10) is the same as (10).  I don't think that is what you intended.

Comment: `-5E-273` is a possible result for you? I think, maybe, you want random integers between -15000 and 15000 ... divided by 10000.

Comment: for IEEE doubles, maybe [something like this ideone](https://ideone.com/igicf6)? (just having fun!)

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize it by creating a function like so:

```
float random_float(float min, float max)
{
    return ((float)rand() / ((float)RAND_MAX)) * (max - min) + min;
}
```

With both `min` and `max` inclusive.

This is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

float random_float(float min, float max)
{
    return ((float)rand() / ((float)RAND_MAX)) * (max - min) + min;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("ran.dat", "w");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%f\n", random_float(-1.5, 1.5));
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

A few things I changed:

- Declared the variable `i` immediately before the `for` loop. This is a good practice, declaring things only when you are about to use them;
- Removed declaration of `float num` as it was unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

This will create 10 random numbers between -1.5 and 1.5.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){ 
    int i;
    float num; 
    srand(time(NULL));
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("ran.dat","w");

    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        num = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX * 3.0 - 1.5;
        fprintf(fp,"%f\n", num);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `float num;` and then `num = (double)...` ??